# react native component inside component

Tags: react-native

I have component that includes a textInput and another component with a slider that also has a textInput. Since both textInputs are exactly the same I am importing the component with the textInput into the component with the slider. When I focus on the textInput I want to make the slider disappear (focus: true -> hide slider , focus: false -> show slider)
Since the textInput is on a child component I'm using a callback to get the focus state of the child and based on this update the focus state on the parent.

The issue is that since I'm updating the state of the parent the whole thing gets rerendered and this also rerenders the child which returns the state again which makes the parent rerender again and makes the child rerender again which makes the child return the state and rerender the parent again and so on.

I did a console.log on both components and it seems this happens around 5 times until it stops. Sometimes with the slider showing even though focus is true other times the slider is hidden.

My question will be how do I make this run only once or at least how do I make the slider always hidden when focus = true (I have merge everything in one component and that solves the issue but I have another view that only needs the textInput so it will be great if I can split this in two components)

Comment: Please edit to add the code you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to change the state of the parent component using a lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate` and that causes the rendering loop. Instead, use a function as a prop to set the new state, then use `shouldComponentUpdate` method like this:

In the child component:

```
func(param) {
  this.props.setParam(param)
}
```

And in the parent component:

```
setParam(param) {
  this.setState(
    // set the param here
  );
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // do something with nextState
}

render() {
  // do something
  return <Child setParam={this.setParam} ... >;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: well I kinda fix it somehow but now I have another issue where the child component isn't receiving the props from the parent.

It's more like a child grandchild relation

Comment: What are you trying to send to child component?

Comment: so the parent component is the Slider that has another component inside with the textInput. When I type something on the textInput I save the text entered using some actions that get pass as props
if I console log(this.props) on the parent I can see them but since the child gets rendered within the parent the child itself is empty
when I do console.log(this.props) on the child component there is nothing there

Comment: Try putting the value of textinput in parent state then send it as a prop from parent state.

Comment: I have some code here to explain it better
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640220/how-to-pass-props-from-component-to-another-component