# How to pass props from component to another component

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have two components, one is rendered inside the other and the parent has some actions that are needed by the child but I don't know how to pass it down

Console Log at the end, I need the actions to get passed to the child because the child needs the action

The thing is the child is already rendered in the same screen so I don't know how to pass this information

Parent component Radius:

```
render(){
    console.log("radiuscomp ", this.props)
    return(
        <View>
            <View>
                <AppHeaderBar onLeftButtonPress = {this.pop} title = "Radius"/>
            </View>
            <ScrollView
            style = {{height: this.state.visibleHeight}}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps = 'always'
            >
                {this.updateContent()}
                <SearchLocation /> //this is the child component 
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
       updateLocationList: state.taskListReducer.consumerTaskLocationHistoryEvent
    };
}

function mapDispatchtoProps(dispatch){
   return bindActionCreators(actions,dispatch);
}

let SearchRadiusContainer = connectEnhance(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchtoProps)(SearchRadiusComponent);
```

Child component Location:

```
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <View style = {Styles.search}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.requestLocationPermission()}>
                    <Image style = {{width: 30, height: 30}} source = {require('../_shared/components/Images/map.png')} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <SearchBox
                ref={ref => (this.autoCompleteInput = ref)}
                onEndEditing={this.dismissLoading}
                onChangeText={text => this.googlePlaceAutoCompletion(text)}
                style={Styles.searchbox}
                placeholder="Suburb or postcode"
                />
            </View>
            {this.alternateHistoryKeywords()}
        </View>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        updateLocationList: state.taskListReducer.consumerTaskLocationHistoryEvent
    };
}

function mapDispatchtoProps(dispatch){
   return bindActionCreators(actions,dispatch);
}

let SearchLocationContainer = connectEnhance(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchtoProps)(SearchLocationComponent);
```

Child need the actions from parent because of this code in child component that saves text input value

```
saveToHistory(){
    let here = false
    this.state.searchLocationList.filter((find, index) => {
        if(find.toLowerCase() == this.state.searchLocation.toLowerCase()){
            here = true
        }
    })
    if(here == false){
        this.setState({
            searchLocationList: [this.state.searchLocation, ...this.state.searchLocationList]
        },()=> this.props.consumerTaskLocationHistoryEventAction(this.state.searchLocationList))  //this action is on parent but not on child
    }
}
```

[Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFzT.jpg)

Comment: what exactly do you want passed down? (tailoring my answer)

Comment: I need to pass those actions down to the child (the ones in console log link because the code of the child uses some of those actions to store the value of the string. It saves a history of what has been added to the text input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please don't use redux to pass props from parent to child. You need to know that you have smart components (connected to redux store) and plain components (know about redux nothing).

Your code should like this

```
state = {
  lon: 54.002,
  lat: 34.990,
}
render() {
  return (
     <Parent>
        <Child {...this.props} lat={this.state.lat} lon={this.state.long} />
     </Parent>
  );
}
```

`{...this.props}` makes a magic and all of your parent props will be passed to a child component. Just connect redux to parent component and add {...this.props} to child

Comment: If you look at the console.log you can see that the parent has all those actions but the child doesn't. I need to pass those actions down to the child

Comment: ohh I get it now, that was simple
sorry didn't understand at first
thanks this works